# How do I force a re-decryption of my local transcrypt objects?

Tags: git, encryption

Transcrypt triggers on a remote git change to pull the latest encrypted version of a file from the origin and decrypt it locally.

I flubbed up my local key, so the decryption failed, but the latest git version of the encrypted transcrypt-related files still exist on my local machine.

I realized my mistake and fixed my local transcrypt encryption key.

Now, Git thinks that these files are the latest version (and they are when compared to the remote origin), but they are encrypted. Git and transcrypt are in a chicken-and-egg scenario: I can't force git to re-pull the files from the remote origin, and I can't get transcrypt to retry the decryption.

I've tried switching branches and that works... sometimes. That doesn't always work because the transcrypt related files are not necessarily different on the remote branch. I was able to clone my current branch into a new branch, modify each encrypted file, and then pull that new branch locally. That kicked transcrypt loose and it worked. There has got to be a more elegant way to do this!

**What command(s) (git and/or transcrypt) do I need to run to get my local files decrypted again?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured this out:

```
transcrypt -d  # (dumps current transcrypt configuration, including key)
transcrypt -f  # (flushes transcrypt credentials and encrypts local files)
```

Then paste the transcrypt configuration line (dumped from transcrypt -d, above) to re-init setup and decrypt local files.

This process takes about 30 seconds; much faster than the remote-branch approach.

Comment: I don't understand how encrypting the local files helps you decrypt them